# Extracting Latitude and Longitude from Polygon Binary Data in PHP

Tags: php, binary, geometry

I'm working on a project where I need to convert Polygon binary data into arrays of latitude and longitude values using PHP. I've attempted to unpack the binary data and organize it into latitude and longitude pairs, but the results seem incorrect or unexpected.

```
[
{
"lat": 1664102448,
"lng": 1717986098
},
{
"lat": 7.786440148571508e-71,
"lng": 1.0408844853708164e-42
},
{
"lat": 4.018325444174134e-57,
"lng": 3.759239572441829e+179
},
{
"lat": 1.3705601230760044e-71,
"lng": 2.1264453324229065e+160
},
{
"lat": 2.3429384547438525e-56,
"lng": 1.657195585293228e-76
},
{
"lat": 1.4844049716462333e-76,
"lng": 1.4864290736513336e-76
},
]
```

The Polygon binary data I have represents geographical coordinates, and I'm trying to extract meaningful latitude and longitude pairs from this data. Here's a snippet of the code I've tried:

```
$wkbHex = '0001e6100000c2cff1357b2a1040af677f02539941403617e48e38781140b738adcb82bb41407c03000000010000006100000a3617e48e387811409111365a67aa414098e4b38b087811400cec49133eab4140fa454eb671771140c8ab4d4c14ac414096d2686574761140f1c11781e9ac4140cafb0a2f117511403028172ebdad414072d940e848731140cdb3a4d08eae414007aea6a41c711140aaeb53e75daf41408145cdb58d6e1140dc2e43f229b04140296b77aa9d6b114092f96a73f2b04140bfcbb04d4e6811408116eceeb6b1414058b4bea5a16411405a8b5ceb76b241409b36ebf299601140b80f13f231b34140e9552bae395c11405ade708fe7b34140d3faa08783571140ccb1295397b441407482f9647a52114044be89d040b541407bd9a95f214d1140c67bb99ee3b54140582c09c37b4711400015ff587fb64140424b4b0a8d4111407950fd9e13b74140affc5bde583b114067cbef14a0b74140e48b9c13e3341140f75ee46324b84140c3fa84a72f2e1140a88af139a0b8414051512abe4227114041c0694a13b94140a69aab9f20201140a66f0b4e7db94140cd3287b5cd18114029b32d03deb94140e81ada874e111140e17ee92d35ba4140b0198bbaa7091140fe373f9882ba4140287f630ade011140199b3812c6ba41403270174af6f9104053db0672ffba4140a9ab3f5ff5f1104035e61c942ebb41406dc6463fe0e91040d2ba455b53bb4140f7e54becbbe1104091c5b6b06dbb4140c708fd718dd9104034341e847dbb41407ef36ae259d11040b738adcb82bb414036ded85226c9104034341e847dbb414005018ad8f7c0104091c5b6b06dbb41408e208f85d3b81040d2ba455b53bb4140523b9665beb0104035e61c942ebb4140c776be7abda8104054db0672ffba4140d56772bad5a01040189b3812c6ba41404bcd4a0a0c991040ff373f9882ba414013ccfb3c65911040e17ee92d35ba414032b44e0fe689104029b32d03deb94140594c2a2593821040a56f0b4e7db94140ac95ab06717b104040c0694a13b9414033ec501d84741040a88af139a0b841401c5b39b1d06d1040f65ee46324b841404eea79e65a67104068cbef14a0b74140bb9b8aba266110407950fd9e13b74140a7bacc01385b10400015ff587fb64140790d2c6592551040c67bb99ee3b541408264dc5f3950104044be89d040b5414017ec343d304b1040ccb1295397b441400591aa167a4610405ade708fe7b341405fb0ead119421040b70f13f231b341409c32171f123e10405a8b5ceb76b24140301b2577653a10407f16eceeb6b14140d07b5e1a1637104090f96a73f2b041406fa1080f26341040d92e43f229b04140f1382f2097311040a8eb53e75daf4140820d95dc6a2f1040ccb3a4d08eae41402bebca95a22d10402f28172ebdad414068146d5f3f2c1040f1c11781e9ac4140ffa0870e422b1040c8ab4d4c14ac414060022239ab2a10400aec49133eab4140c2cff1357b2a10409111365a67aa4140eebeb2c34f2b1040432a9579baa84140f7b74679bd2d10401df983cb11a74140cf6e7529be311040ca4a446671a541405e3767c947371040c6d9344bdda34140dcd11a8b4c3e1040ba76fd5c59a241400c12ea00bb4610406cf50a56e9a04140fb82b7497e5010402db371bf909f41404c8c4c457e5b1040636e4ce8529e4140338f5ed09f671040d7daabdd329d4140e306a207c574104079e92963339c41409aea4491cd821040511e32ec569b4140a66b1dec96911040ed920e969f9a4140a69ccfc3fca01040b468c7220f9a4140caa12349d9b01040e77ae0f4a699414068a5be8d05c110400217ff0b689941407ef36ae259d11040af677f025399414093411737aee110400117ff0b689941402e45b27bdaf11040e77ae0f4a6994140534a0601b7011140b368c7220f9a41404e7bb8d81c111140ef920e969f9a414057fc9033e61f1140501e32ec569b414017e033bdee2d114077e92963339c4140b75777f4133b1140d7daabdd329d4140a95a897f35471140636e4ce8529e4140f9631e7b355211402db371bf909f4140ead4ebc3f85b11406bf50a56e9a041401315bb3967641140ba76fd5c59a241409aaf6efb6b6b1140c6d9344bdda341402078609bf5701140ca4a446671a54140032f8f4bf67411401df983cb11a741400728230164771140432a9579baa841403617e48e387811409111365a67aa4140fe
'; 

$unpack = unpack("VSRID/corder/ltype/Lnum_rings/Lnum_points/d*", $wkbHex, 0);
array_shift($unpack);
array_shift($unpack);

if (count($unpack)%2) {
    array_shift($unpack);
}

$data = array_chunk($unpack, 2);
$return = [];

for ($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i++) {
    $return[] = [
        'lat' => $data[$i][0],
        'lng' => $data[$i][1],
    ];
}

return $return;
```

However, the latitude and longitude pairs obtained from this process are not aligning correctly with the expected coordinates. I suspect that my interpretation or handling of the binary data might be incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

You should decode WKB format for polygons into latitude and longitude coordinates, considering byte order and reading polygon structure (number of rings and points) from the binary data like the following

```
$wkbHex = ''; // add your WKB here

$wkbBinary = hex2bin($wkbHex);

//Check endianness
$endianness = unpack('C', $wkbBinary[0])[1];
$isLittleEndian = ($endianness === 1);

$format = $isLittleEndian ? 'Vtype/Lnum_rings/Lnum_points' : 'Ntype/Nnum_rings/Nnum_points';

$header = unpack($format, $wkbBinary);

$offset = 9;

$coordinates = [];
for ($ring = 0; $ring < $header['num_rings']; $ring++) {
    // Number of points in the ring
    $num_points = unpack('L', substr($wkbBinary, $offset, 4))[1];
    $offset += 4;

    for ($point = 0; $point < $num_points; $point++) {
        $latLng = unpack('d2', substr($wkbBinary, $offset, 16));
        $offset += 16;

        $coordinates[] = [
            'lat' => $latLng[1],
            'lng' => $latLng[2]
        ];
    }
}

return $coordinates;
```

Comment: unpack(): Type d: not enough input, need 8, have 7

Comment: also l have same output 1466.86317411923548.5923555555-1.4149498567667E-73-1.0340084160986E-22-1